# Displaying parse errors in module development on the browser

Tags: 7

I am currently trying to learn Drupal Module development.

As one might guess, many errors get created in the process. But, all i can see is WSOD on the browser.

For the same errors, most of the Module development videos on youtube show display the errors on the browser itself in an easy to understand format with specific details on the parse error(attached image).
[image]
I have tried some solutions on configuring on index.php, but in vain. Also, I can see the errors on Drush, but that doesn't satiate

Could anyone please tell me on how i can have this in my environment?

I'm running Drupal 7 on Windows 8 using Bitnami WAMP Stack.

Comment: That's XDebug - install the extension into your version of PHP, enable and configure, turn Drupal's error reporting up to maximum through the UI, et voila

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable error displaying in PHP. There are several ways to do it, but one of the most straightforward is to enable them in the settings.php of your project.

Just add those lines to the file:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$conf['error_level'] = 2;
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

Meaning:

1. Instruct PHP to notify all errors.
2. Instructs Drupal to show all errors (using a drupal_set_message).
3. Instruct PHP to display errors instead of show a blank page.
4. Instruct PHP to display errors even those in the startup phase.

Also, as Clive comments, if you enable XDebug error reporting is more verbose. The screenshot you show includes XDdebug error backtrace.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Much appreciated. 

I am getting the errors displayed in this format:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting ')' in C:\Users\ajay.un\Downloads\wampstack-5.6.18-0\apache2\htdocs\test\sites\all\modules\custom\mymod\mymod.module on line 90


Can i not have it in a better way, like the one enclosed in screenshot? 
Also, like Clive mentioned, can i have Xdebug installed on windows? 

Apologies if my questions sond silly - I am new to these dev envts.

Comment: You have to enable Xdebug, and yes, you can have it installed on windows, but those are different questions. Serach onDrupal Answers or create new ones.

Answer (score 0):

Just add below lines in your site's settings.php

```php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

More details you can find from [Show all errors while developing](https://www.drupal.org/node/1056468)